# How can I convert this array to an object?

Tags: php, arrays, object

How can i convert an array like this to object?

```
Array
(
    [max] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21.
            [1] => male.
            [2] => UK.
        )

    [alex] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20.
            [1] => male.
            [2] => sweden.
        )

    [ali] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20.
            [1] => male.
            [2] => saudi arabia.
        )

)
```

i've alrady tried for each loop and it didn't work. 
is there any way to convert it ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: evreything! and nothing worked

Comment: "everything!" doesn't tell us much. Please [edit] your question with attempted solutions, and tell us why they failed.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
 $object =  json_decode(json_encode($array));
```

or you can also do this.

```
$object = (object) $array;
```

Here's a [demo](https://eval.in/159861).

Comment: i alrady tried it and i have an error
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in ....

Comment: @MaxZag Whats the error?

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in ....

Comment: @MaxZag that error is unrelated to transforming an array to object array, this error appears when your trying to echo an object array

Comment: @MaxZag like Darly Gill said the error occurs because your accessing properties of the object wrongly. Try using $object->variableName; And see the updated answer the conversion works fine.